# помогите найти фреймворк (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animation

помогите найти фреймворк, который мог бы сделать [такую анимацию](http://www.lunargravity.be/) (с картинками которая)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/cvcpzknp/6/

Идея такая. Если есть необходимость в поддержке более старых браузеров, то надо добавить соответствующие префиксы и, возможно, поменять единицу измерения.

```js
function update() {
    var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop();
    var vh = $(window).height() / 100;
    
    $("main section").each(function(i) {
        var section = $(this);
        var angle = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (section.offset().top - (scrolled + 10*vh)) / (100 * vh)));
        console.log(i, section.offset().top - (scrolled + 10*vh), angle);
        section.css('transform', 'rotate(' + (i&1 ? '-' : '') + angle*8 + 'deg)');
    });
}

$(document).scroll(update);
$(window).resize(update);
$(update);
```

```css
header {
    height: 50vh;
}

main {
    overflow: hidden;
}

main section {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background: silver;
    margin: 1vh auto;
    transition: transform linear .25s;
    transform-origin: top left;
}

main section:nth-child(even) {
    transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    Some content to be scrolled
</header>
<main>
    <section>First</section>
    <section>Second</section>
    <section>Third</section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о анимации логотипа, то там просто анимированная gif'ка на hover показывается:

```
.logo:hover img:first-child { display:none }
.logo:hover .logo-gif { display:block }
```

Если есть желание сделать подобное средствами css, то надо использовать keyframes. Хотя, кажется где-то писали, что с измененияем фона из них проблемы могут быть. Надо проверять.

Comment: спасибо, но имелось ввиду другое, анимация при скроллинге, большие блоки как бы меняют свой rotate, меня вот это интересует

Comment: Понял. Вечером отвечу, если не забуду. Это не сложно сделать.